# Prove $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = L$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $f(x) = g(1/x)$ for $x>0$. Prove: $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L \iff \lim_{x \to 0} g(x) = L$ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$.

I assume I am supposed to use l'Hopital's rule in some way (considering that is what section we are in). I've tried looking at the definition of a limit and the sequential criterion for limits, but I have no idea where to go.

Just a push in the right direction would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's wrong as stated. It should be $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$. No L'Hôpital. Just use definitions of limit.

Comment: Look at definitions of those limits.

Comment: @leo So $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) =L$ means for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $M>0$ such that $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ whenever $x>M$. And $\lim_{x \to 0} g(x)=L$ means for each $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<x<\delta$. Not sure what to do from here... if it's slapping me in the face, let me know!

Comment: Yes that's correct. You have to assume that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$ and then use it to prove that $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(1/x) = L$. And the other way around: assume $\lim_{x\to 0^{+}} f(1/x) = L$ to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = L$.

Comment: If you're comfortable with the extended reals, you can solve this problem by recognizing that $1/x$ extends to a continuous function on the interval $[0,+\infty]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You know

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists y>0:\forall x>y: |f(x)-L|<\epsilon,$$

i.e.

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists y>0:\forall x>y: |g(1/x)-L|<\epsilon,$$

i.e.

$$\forall\epsilon>0:\exists y>0:\forall 0<x<1/y: |g(x)-L|<\epsilon,$$

and vice versa.

Comment: Well yes, but this look so awful. Could you write in english? After all you'd use keyboard, and well we are no robots.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks!

Comment: @leo: I thought this was a math forum?! ;-)  But you're right, of course, that it never hurts to have some explanation to go with the formulas.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the right direction:

Given $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ we know $\exists N : x> N \Rightarrow |f(x) -L| < \epsilon$.

Set $x' = \frac 1 x$ and $\delta = \frac 1 N$. Then $x>N \Leftarrow\Rightarrow x' < \frac 1 N = \delta$.

Thus $x' < \delta \Rightarrow x> N \Rightarrow |f(x) -L| = |f(\frac 1 {x'}) -L| = |g(x') -L| < \epsilon$. And so $\lim_{x' \rightarrow 0}g(x') = L$.

Note: We are actually assuming $x'>0$, so the limit only works as $x'$ approaches $0$ from the right.